# AWS SES send email with mutt

Tags: amazon-ec2, sendmail, amazon-ses, mutt

I have set up the sendmail in EC2 to send out email with the instruction provided by AWS:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-sendmail.html
But I can't find any instruction to set up mutt on EC2, I want to use mutt instead of sendmail as I want to send with file attachment. Can anyone tell me how I can set up the mutt on EC2 to send email?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did the [sendmail setting](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#sendmail) work?

Comment: Yes, the sendmail setting work ok, but just could not add the attachment on it

Answer (score 0):

`mutt` can be used with AWS SES.

The first step is to ensure that you have a verified email address for sending via SES. Follow this guide here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email.html) to get to stage where you have verified your email address.

Once you are at the point, simply create or update your `.muttrc` file:

```
set from="Your verfied email address <verfied@example.com>"
set smtp_url="smtp://YOURAWS_SES_USERNAME@email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:587"  #Swap out email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com with whatever email region you are using
set smtp_pass="YOURAWS_SES_PasswordHere"
```

That's all you'll need.

Comment: This is not all in case your AWS account is in the SES _Sandbox Mode_. The current mode is shown in the AWS SES Console under *Account dashboard*. In the Sandbox Mode you also need to verify the email recipient addresses.

Comment: @Yuri That's true. My answer above was specific to his statement "I have set up the sendmail in EC2 to send out email with the instruction provided by AWS:". However you make a good point: If you've not reached the stage hobbyking was at, you will need to get out of the sandbox mode and potentially verify email addresses.
P.S. Thanks for the formatting edit - it looks much better :-)